# Laravel routing failing for controller

Tags: php, laravel

Its Laravel 5.
When the route.php contains this:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

then the page shows with the text "Hello World".

However, as soon as I add this new line in route.php:

```
Route::get('/foo2', 'IndexController');
```

then the page show this error:

```
UnexpectedValueException in Route.php line 567: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\IndexController]
```

I previously created a controller with artisan which now looks like this:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify wich method will be executed:

```
Route::get('/foo2', 'IndexController@index');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using get method of Route. **Normally** first argument provided should be the `url` and second argument should be the `method` (there are other ways argument could be passed)

```
Route::get('/foo2', 'IndexController@index');
```

If you want to  resourceful route . **Normally** first argument should be the resource name and the second argument should be RESTful controller name. *(there are other ways argument could be passed)*.Example: photo is the resource name and PhotoController is the controller name.

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

in your case it should work this way

```
Route::resource('/foo2', 'IndexController');
```

or

```
Route::get('/foo2', 'IndexController@index');
```

so when you visit

```
yoursite.com/foo2
```

you will be displayed with IndexController index method

See reference more to learn laravel's restful resource controller

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the function inside the controller not just the controller:

```
Route::get('/foo2', 'IndexController@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions, use

```
Route::get('/myroute', [MyController::class, 'methodName']); 
//or
Route::get('/myroute', ['App\\Controllers\\MyController', 'methodName']);
```

You have to reference *Controller@method* as:

```
Route::get('/myroute', ['uses' => 'MyController@methodName']);
//or
Route::get('/myroute', 'MyController@methodName');
```